# Подключение Servlet к проекту

Tags: java, servlet

Взял программу в которой подключён Servlet и его не видит. Программа написана на Эклипсе, я же запускаю в IDEA. В чёмможет быть проблема? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А библиотека 
     `<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>`
есть в classpath?

Comment: @Темкатоже а как это посмотреть?

Comment: Правой кнопкой на корневую папку проекта -> `Open Module Settings` -> `Project Setttings/Libraries`. Если её там нет, то [скачай](http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar) и добавь при помощи зеленого плюса.